# Python: weight conversion script issue

Tags: python

I'm currently learning Python and I'm doing an exercise in which I'm making a weight converter. I keep on running into this issue, can any1 plz help?

```
weight = int(input("How much do you weigh? "))
unit = input("Was that in (K)gs or (L)bs? ")

if unit == "L" or "l":
    converted = weight * 0.45
    print("Kgs: {0}".format(converted))

if unit == "K" or "k":
    converted = weight / 0.45
    print("Lbs: {0}".format(converted))
```

The terminal just prints both. I have no idea what the problem is.

Comment: you need to use `elif` otherwise both conditions will be evaluated. In addition, you are not using properly `or`, so that is why you always get printed that.

Comment: You need `if unit == "L" or unit == "l"`. Right now it is doing `if (unit == "L") or ("l")` and `"l"` evaluates to `true`. (Note that in Python, *most* values convert to `true` when converted to booleans. For strings, lists, and other collections of objects, usually the only state that evaluates to `false` is an empty string, or an empty list.)

Comment: I am downvoting because your title is not useful and somewhat disrespectful of the people that come to help here voluntarily.

Answer (score 2):

Update your code to:

```py
weight = int(input("How much do you weigh? "))
unit = input("Was that in (K)gs or (L)bs? ")

if unit in ["L", "l"]:
    converted = weight * 0.45
    print("Kgs: {0}".format(converted))

elif unit in ["K", "k"]:
    converted = weight / 0.45
    print("Lbs: {0}".format(converted))
```

You are facing basically two problems:

1. You need to use `if ... : elif ...:`. Otherwise, the conditions will be always evaluated.
2. You are not using `or` properly. `unit == "L" or "l"` will be always evaluated to `True`, what you want to check is whether your input is `"k"` or `"K"`, so you have some alternatives:

- `unit in ["K", "k"]`
- `unit == "k" or unit == "K"`
- `unit.tolower() == "k"`
- `unit.toupper() == "K"`

Answer (score 1):

```py
if unit == "L" or unit ==  "l":
    converted = weight * 0.45
    print("Kgs: {0}".format(converted))

elif unit == "K" or unit == "k":
    converted = weight / 0.45
    print("Lbs: {0}".format(converted))
```